# How to enforce/redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, iis-6, redirect, https

I've been hosting a domain on a Win2003 server for the last 3 or 4 years, but I now need to make this domain accessible only via HTTPS.

I've installed the certificate correctly and it works fine (the server hosts several domains, but this domain is hosted on a different public IP address), but I'm struggling to get IIS to just transfer all users who go to http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com.

I've found the "require secure channel" option in IIS, but checking this results in anyone who fails to type the `https://` part seeing an error message (below). What's the best way to redirect users to the HTTPS site (without the user having to worry about it)?

> The page must be viewed over a secure channel The page you are trying to
>       access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
>
> Please try the following:
>
> Type https:// at the beginning of the address you are attempting to reach
>       and press ENTER.
>
> HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden: SSL is required to view this resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS using IIS](http://www.codescene.com/2006/03/redirecting-http-to-https-usin.php)

> With SSL enabled, anytime you attempt
>   to access a page via http, the server
>   generates a 403.4 error. IIS is now
>   configured to run your sslredirect.asp
>   page every time this error occurs. The
>   error page will include a querystring
>   which contains the error number and
>   the page causing the error, I.e.
>   "403;http://www.whatever.com". Our ASP
>   file uses a simple script to just trim
>   off the beginning part (430;http), add
>   the necessary "https", and redirect to
>   whatever page the user requested using
>   SSL. Voila!

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is to have a mod rewrite isapi filter installed.  And redirect all http calls to https (or just those for a specific folder/page if you prefer).

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Heres an article that explains how to do that + mentions some of the others suggested.
http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/three_methods_redirect_http_https

Comment: I disagree with the first part; many adjectives spring to mind when thinking about the ISAPI version of mod_rewrite, but "clean" isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Microsoft Knowledgebase article [How to redirect an HTTP connection to HTTPS for Outlook Web Access clients and how to redirect the Default Web Site to point to the Exchange virtual directory](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839357).

There are a few steps to configure this correctly; the code is:

```asp
<%

If Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")  = "off" Then
Response.Redirect "https://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & "/Exchange"
End If 

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your redirect setup, make sure to also add [HSTS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) to your requests. This skips the redirect step entirely after users have visited your site once. So subsequent visits will not need to be redirected since browsers make a https connection right away.

You can also get your site added to a [preload service](https://hstspreload.org/), which all major browsers include so that users connect to https even on their first visit.

Comment: This question was asked in 2009, and the HSTS RFC is from November 2012. Hopefully this Windows 2003 (EOL since July 2015)  is not alive anymore.

Comment: Ah good point, I hadn't even noticed the date. I came here via google while trying to search for the term 'HSTS' because I had forgotten the name. So I figured at least someone could benefit from this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have your publishing firewall do the redirect. Having calls reaching the actual web server which it has no business dealing with seems unnecessary and may even pose a security risk.